# How to fix "the C++ compiler is not able to compile a simple tst program" with Cmake and Android-NDK

Tags: cmake, android-ndk, clang, clang++

When trying to compile a project using Cmake and Android NDK, it says the following:
The C++ Comnpiler "/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++" is not able to compile a simple test program.

Im using Cmake 3.8 and Android NDK r18.
In CMakelists the CXX compiler is set to g++, so I dont know why it wants to use clang++.

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (project)

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
  The C++ compiler

```
"/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++"
```

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
    Change Dir: /builder/DualBootPatcher/builder/android/android-app_arm64-v8a-prefix/src/android-app_arm64-v8a-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_48d2d/fast"
    gmake[3]: Entering directory '/builder/DualBootPatcher/builder/android/android-app_arm64-v8a-prefix/src/android-app_arm64-v8a-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_48d2d.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_48d2d.dir/build
    gmake[4]: Entering directory '/builder/DualBootPatcher/builder/android/android-app_arm64-v8a-prefix/src/android-app_arm64-v8a-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_48d2d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /usr/bin/ccache /opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk/sysroot   -isystem /opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem /opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include  -isystem /opt/android-ndk/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -target aarch64-none-linux-android21 -gcc-toolchain /opt/android-ndk/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11   -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_48d2d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /builder/DualBootPatcher/builder/android/android-app_arm64-v8a-prefix/src/android-app_arm64-v8a-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    ccache: error: Failed to create directory /builder/.ccache/tmp: Permission denied
    gmake[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_48d2d.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_48d2d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o] Error 1
    gmake[4]: Leaving directory '/builder/DualBootPatcher/builder/android/android-app_arm64-v8a-prefix/src/android-app_arm64-v8a-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    gmake[3]: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_48d2d/fast] Error 2
    gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/builder/DualBootPatcher/builder/android/android-app_arm64-v8a-prefix/src/android-app_arm64-v8a-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/builder/DualBootPatcher/builder/android/android-system_armeabi-v7a-prefix/src/android-system_armeabi-v7a-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/builder/DualBootPatcher/builder/android/android-system_armeabi-v7a-prefix/src/android-system_armeabi-v7a-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/builder/DualBootPatcher/builder/android/android-app_armeabi-v7a-prefix/src/android-app_armeabi-v7a-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/builder/DualBootPatcher/builder/android/android-app_armeabi-v7a-prefix/src/android-app_armeabi-v7a-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/builder/DualBootPatcher/builder/android/android-app_arm64-v8a-prefix/src/android-app_arm64-v8a-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/builder/DualBootPatcher/builder/android/android-app_arm64-v8a-prefix/src/android-app_arm64-v8a-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make[2]: *** [android/CMakeFiles/android-app_armeabi-v7a.dir/build.make:106: android/android-app_armeabi-v7a-prefix/src/android-app_armeabi-v7a-stamp/android-app_armeabi-v7a-configure] Error 1
make[2]: *** [android/CMakeFiles/android-system_armeabi-v7a.dir/build.make:106: android/android-system_armeabi-v7a-prefix/src/android-system_armeabi-v7a-stamp/android-system_armeabi-v7a-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1098: android/CMakeFiles/android-app_armeabi-v7a.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1396: android/CMakeFiles/android-system_armeabi-v7a.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [android/CMakeFiles/android-app_arm64-v8a.dir/build.make:106: android/android-app_arm64-v8a-prefix/src/android-app_arm64-v8a-stamp/android-app_arm64-v8a-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1322: android/CMakeFiles/android-app_arm64-v8a.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

Comment: What stands out in the output is `ccache: error: Failed to create directory /builder/.ccache/tmp: Permission denied`. What environment are you running this under, and how does it involve CCache?

Comment: Since you are cross compiling using CMake you should provide the cmake command line AND the CMakeToolchainFile you used...

Comment: please note that by default `project()` enable language CXX so cmake check the compiler on it reach the project() line -> did you set CXX before the project(), command ? otherwise you coulde use `project(... LANGUAGES NONE)` then later `enable_language(CXX)` IIRC

Comment: @Botje Im running Ubuntu 18.10, Cmake is running in a docker container. I dont know how this involves Ccache, im a noob in programming. Im just following the instructions to build this, but it only gives errors and errors.

Comment: @Mizux The Cmake command is: `cd DualBootPatcher/builder && cmake .. -DMBP_BUILD_TARGET=android -DMBP_BUILD_TYPE=debug && make -j16 && rm -rf` and this is the toolchain file: https://pastebin.com/cmu9sG48